# I got no implicit conversion of Symbol into String when I create a new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a **no implicit conversion of Symbol into String** error when I try to create a new record... 
What am I missing here?? (Rails 5) (Title is a string and description is text though...)
below my controller:

```
class JobOffersController < ApplicationController

  def index
     @job_offers = JobOffer.all
  end

  def new
    @job_offer = JobOffer.new
  end

  def create
    @job_offer = JobOffer.create(job_offer_params)
    if @job_offer.save
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "yeahhh"
    else
      render :new, alert: "boohh"
    end
  end

  private

  def job_offer_params
    require(:job_offer).permit(:title, :description)
  end
end
```

When I try to create a new record, here is what appears in the terminal...
What is wrong??

```
 Started POST "/job_offers" for ::1 at 2017-05-13 11:53:21 +0200
Processing by JobOffersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"SKJDBCshiZoppprNPMQ5f/2C5zGuyvBJFsatyUlUdYFlKmLxcCk/WeX5po8xHwKaEDB+2RshbcqVfssm4agKBg==", "job_offer"=>{"title"=>"test", "description"=>"ploc"}, "commit"=>"Create Job offer"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



TypeError - no implicit conversion of Symbol into String:
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
  app/controllers/job_offers_controller.rb:23:in `job_offer_params'
  app/controllers/job_offers_controller.rb:12:in `create'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:188:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
  activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:126:in `process'
  actionview (5.0.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in `call'
  rack (2.0.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (2.0.2) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'
  rack (2.0.2) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
  rack (2.0.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
  rack (2.0.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
  activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:553:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
  web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
  web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
  railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
  railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
  railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
  sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (2.0.2) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (2.0.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
  rack (2.0.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
  railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
  puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
  puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:600:in `handle_request'
  puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
  puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
  puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing `params` here in front of `require`

```
def job_offer_params
  params.require(:job_offer).permit(:title, :description)
end
```